Unable to set State in React in UseEffect With 'popstate' eventListener
I have a useEffect in React. In this useEffect I have a popstate eventListener. This eventListener successfully triggers if I visit the page, then visit another page, then press back to go back to the page with this code on it.
Although the eventListener trigger, if I try to set state inside the function attached to the event listener and then log the state to the console, the state is always undefined. This is not the case if I use a pageshow eventListener, so I am reasonably confident it has to do with popstate.
I have tried using a setTimeout around the state. I have tried moving the function outside the useEffect. I have also tried using useLayoutEffect. Neither work and the state is always undefined.
How can I use a popstate event listener to successfully set the state? I need to do something when the user arrives at the page from the back or forward button.
useEffect(() => {
  const handlePopState = () => {
     setSomeState("test value"); 
  };

  window.addEventListener('popstate', handlePopState);

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('popstate', handlePopState);
  };
}, []);


Your component is being rendered after popstate fires. Using global route listeners doesn't make much sense in a single page app. You probably need a React based router.

The following code works:
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [someState, setSomeState] = useState('');

  history.pushState({ page: 1 }, 'title 1', '?page=1');
  history.back();

  useEffect(() => {
    const handlePopState = () => {
      console.log('event');
      setSomeState('test value');
    };

    window.addEventListener('popstate', handlePopState);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('popstate', handlePopState);
    };
  }, []);
  return <>the new state is {someState}</>;
}


that looks like you're triggering the event manually in the component. i need to capture the event when the page loads and the user has arrived at the page from pressing the back button.

The objective of this code is to bring up the point that this event will trigger when the pages are accessed in a particular sequence. If we can follow the same sequence manually, then the code will trigger for sure. There are 14 points connected with popstate to fire properly, request you may please see the section here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_event . I yet to have a need on this topic, therefore I still to give some time into this section.

The summary of my post and the comment is : Your code is well set, the missing point is popstate will fire when the pages are chosen in the sequence du to to fire it.  Please revert in case it may require more attention from me.
